# How to use "first something + ever"

Tags: present-perfect, past-vs-present-perfect

I learnt at school that you use perfect form + ever with "This is the first time", such as "This is the first time I have ever eaten sushi."

But I recently encountered "She was the first girlfriend I ever had."

- She was the first girlfriend I ever had.
- She was the first girlfriend I had ever had.

Are they both fine?  Is it because it is past tense?  How about present tense?

- She is the first girlfriend I ever have.
- She is the first girlfriend I have ever had.

Are they both OK?

Comment: How is this different from [your other question about the same grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/327536/this-is-the-first-time-present-perfect)?

Comment: What are you saying?  YOU are the one who told me to make my question about just one.  THAT is why I split the question into two, one about SHE WAS THE FIRST GIRLFRIEND and one about THIS IS THE FIRST TIME.

Comment: "She was the first girlfriend that I ever had" is past and "This is the first time that I have eaten sushi" is present.  In addition, "that" in the former sentence is a relative pronoun while "that" in the latter is a conjunction.  Therefore, I posted the question into two.  SO, I have ABSOLUTELY NO IDEA why you ask me the difference from my other question.  IT WAS YOU who closed my question before and told me to make one question about just one thing.  I had no choice but to post two questions this time because I didn't want you to close my question again.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. I just remembered seeing three very similar questions in the last day. I looked at your other two, but didn't see the one I'd closed. You've done it right and I just forgot. In future, if you're asking questions that are very similar at the same time, to stop people like me from making comments, you could mention the other question and say what's different. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really about *adverb placement*. You should do some research about this, and you will find there is often room for variation.

- She was the first girlfriend I **ever** had.
- She was my first girlfriend **ever**.
- She was my first **ever** girlfriend.

Your second example...

> She was the first girlfriend I had ever had.

... isn't *wrong*, it's just unnecessarily long. People don't think too hard about things like this when speaking extemporaneously. If that's what you're trying to capture in your prose then it's fine.

Your first present tense example is incorrect. This is because 'ever' means eternally into the *past* or into the *future*. You can't talk about the present that way. So, "*she is the first girlfriend I ever have*" makes no sense.

You *could* say:

> She is the *only* girlfriend I *will ever* have.

Although a bit presumptuous, it is grammatically correct because you are looking into the future.

But your last example is fine because it is looking into the past:

> She is the first girlfriend I have ever had.

This means she is your first *until now*.